# existence of certain function on unit interval

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, continuity

I'm trying to solve this exercise in an introductory book on general topology:

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $A,B \subset X$ disjoint closed subsets.
Show that there exists a continuous function $f: X \rightarrow [0,1]$ such that $f^{-1}  (\{0\}) = A$ and $f^{-1}  (\{1\}) = B$.

I came up with a solution for the special case that $A=\{a\}$ and $B=\{b\}$ for some $a,b \in X$ with $a \neq b$.

In this case, one can take

$f(x) = \frac{\min(d(a,b),d(a,x))+\max(0,d(a,b)-d(x,b))}{2d(a,b)}$

I had the idea to generalize this using the distance function between a point and a subset.

Let $c = \inf \{ d(x,B) | x \in A \} = \inf \{ d(A,x) | x \in B \} = \inf \{ d(x,y) | x \in A, y \in B \}$

Then define f as

$f(x)= \frac{\min(c,d(x,A))+\max(0,c-d(x,B))}{2c}$

It is not difficult to show that this function has the desired properties, but this only works if c is non-zero. Take for example $ X = \mathbb R \setminus \{0\}$ with the restriction of the euclidean metric and $A = \{\frac{1}{n} | n \in \mathbb N \}$ and $B = \{-\frac{1}{n} | n \in \mathbb N \}$. Then A and B are closed in $X$, but $c=0$. Is there a way to fix this or is there a totally differenct solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a subset $E$ of a (pseudo-)metric space $X$, define $\rho_E(x) = \inf\{d(x,y):y\in E\}$. I hope you know that $\rho_E(x) = 0$ iff $x\in \bar{E}$. Given your problem, simply set
$$
f(x) = \frac{\rho_A(x)}{\rho_A(x)+\rho_B(x)}.
$$

Comment: Thank you, I was thinking to complicated.